# multi-line payload is treated as single line in python request

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests, content-type

I am simulating a post request where user sends multiline body data in post request.
as per expectation this should be treated as multi line but on the application side this is treated as single line .

below payload is read from csv file using

```
with open(f"test_file.csv") as r:
        payload = r.read()
```

data in test_file.csv is -->

```
CO000PMAT;AFACT000PMAT;22/03/2022;1;PNRTE;;;EUR;;Reason
CO001PMAT;AFACT001PMAT;22/03/2022;2;PNRTE;;;EUR;;Reason
```

python request:

```
response = requests.post('https://example.com/api/v1/data?fileName=test_file.txt', data = payload, headers= {'Authorization':'XXXXX', 'Content-Type' : 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'})
```

in my expectation payload should be treated as 2 lines but in reality application is treating this as a single line .

could anybody suggest something  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is resolved by opening file in 'rb' mode .

```
with open("test_file.txt",'rb') as r:
        payload = r.read()
```